# UDP receive buffer error

Tags: linux, performance, udp

We are running opensips SIP proxy in high traffic environment, it's using UDP protocol. We are seeing sometime `RX` error or overrun error on interface. I have set `rmem_max to 16M` but still i am seeing error this is what i am seeing in netstat. any idea how to fix this error?

We have 40 CPU and 64GB memory on system so it is not a resource issue.

One more thing, we are running tcpdump on it and capturing all SIP traffic. do you think `tcpdump` can cause that issue?

netstat -su

```
Udp:
    27979570 packets received
    2727 packets to unknown port received.
    724419 packet receive errors
    41731936 packets sent
    322 receive buffer errors
    0 send buffer errors
    InCsumErrors: 55
```

Dropwatch -l kas

```
846 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
3 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
4 drops at unix_stream_connect+2ca (0xffffffff815a388a)
552 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
503 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
4 drops at unix_stream_connect+2ca (0xffffffff815a388a)
1557 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
6 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
1203 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
2051 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
1940 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
541 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
221 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
745 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
389 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
568 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
651 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
622 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
377 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
1 drops at tcp_rcv_state_process+1b0 (0xffffffff81550f70)
577 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
9 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
135 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
217 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
358 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
211 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
337 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
54 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
105 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
27 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
42 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
249 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
1080 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
1932 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
1476 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
681 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
840 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
1076 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
1021 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
1 drops at tcp_rcv_state_process+1b0 (0xffffffff81550f70)
294 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
186 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
313 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
257 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
132 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
1 drops at tcp_rcv_state_process+1b0 (0xffffffff81550f70)
343 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
282 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
191 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
303 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
96 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
223 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
1 drops at tcp_rcv_state_process+1b0 (0xffffffff81550f70)
183 drops at tpacket_rcv+5f (0xffffffff815e46ff)
```

Comment: Why are you running tcpdump in a production system with a high use?

Comment: we are capturing `sip.pcap` for troubleshooting.

Comment: I would suggest doing port mirroring at switch level and capturing traffic with tcpdump in another machine.

Comment: I like your idea but we are using cloud and SDN network it's no fun because you don't know sometime where your machine running with bunch of other services.

Comment: PS, where possible, please include the kernel version you report your results from (or version of whatever software your results come from).  The results might look different on some future kernel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lookup `tpacket_rcv`: it's in `af_packet.c`.  `AF_PACKET` means tcpdump.

It looks like someone else saw a problem triggered by tcpdump, without resolution: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mechanical-sympathy/qLqYTouygTE/rq9XSBxgqiMJ

But I'm suspicious about drops in tpacket_rcv.  Probably it means function exit via the label `ring_is_full`.  It sounds like packets will not reach tcpdump because its buffer is overflowing.  However I don't think this means the packet is (necessarily) being dropped completely; it can still reach the UDP socket.  It suggests your dropwatch transcript didn't cover any of the UDP drops shown in the counters.  I don't think AF_PACKET are being counted as UDP drops just because they're both datagram sockets.  Unfortunately it looks like these `tp_drops` are not shown by `netstat`.

I would want to run dropwatch and filter out the tpacket_rcv lines with `grep -v`.  Just long enough to see an increase in your UDP receive error counter.

I think `rmem_max` for UDP will only help if the app tries to raise receive buffers.  No real search results for "opensips rmem".  I would try raising `rmem_default` instead.  But I really hope they would be shown as "receive buffer errors" if that was the problem...

And yet, they're not UDP checksum errors either...

There's another tunable called `netdev_max_backlog`.  Apparently the corresponding overflow counter is the second column of `/proc/net/softnet_stat` (there's one row per cpu).  But this happens before the packet is fed to the UDP stack, so it shouldn't have this affect the UDP statistics...

Whelp, that's all I can think of now, it's a bit mysterious :(.

**EDIT**:

> There is a setting in SIP proxy server related buffer size that size was small to handle high pps rate.  After adjust that we are seeing good result.  Drops are there, but very very low counts. – Satish

Comment: There is a setting in SIP proxy server related buffer size that size was small to handle high pps rate, after adjust that we are seeing good result drops are there but very very low counts.

Comment: @Satish thank you! That's useful to know. I.e. that overflow of socket buffers may appear as "packet receive errors" etc.; it is not very obvious.  And of course it is useful for anyone who has the exact same problem as you.  I have edited my answer to include your comment.